# how can i Create indexed variable in perl?

Tags: perl

I am new to perl, how can i create indexed variable like $Num0, $Num1 and   $value0, $value1. I have to store  some value from hash in this variable.

```
 $Num0 = $req->{value0};
 $Num1 = $req->{value1};
 $Num2 = $req->{value2};
```

is it possible to crate both variable Num0,Num1 and value0,value1 using some logic based on indexing like below.

```
while($i < 5)
{
 $Num.$i = $req->{value$i};
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use perl arrays.

```
my @num;
my $i=0;
while ($i<5) {
    $num[$i] = $req->{"value$i"};
    $i++;
}
```

See [perl cheatsheet](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlcheat.html) for concise help on perl.

@ikegami suggested some alternative ways to do the same thing in comments:

```
my @num = map { $ref->{"index$_"} } (0..4);
```

and

```
my @num;
for my $i (0..4) {
    push @num, $ref->{"index$i"};
}
```

See help on [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [`push`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html).